# Cannot access website with custom domain name

Tags: heroku, dns, ovh

I have deployed my application on Heroku and I have issues setting my custom domain name.

Here are my domains on Heroku :
[image]

Here are my targets set on OVH :
[image]

Still, I cannot access my website and the browser states that the website is not accessible with this error appended : DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a well written article on their site that outlines the steps:

[Custom Domain Names for Apps](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#configuring-dns-for-root-domains)

Also, an important part is that your account is verified:

> You can add custom domains to any Heroku app . . . you must verify your Heroku account to add domains to apps.

[Account Verification](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/account-verification)